# Using an appserver.io SessionBean in a plain php script

Tags: php, appserver

I am looking for a way to replace select functionality in an existing application with appserver.io SessionBeans, but I fail to find an example on how to access a SessionBean in a plain php class.

I have a super simple Singleton SessionBean from the examples:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyApp;

/**
 * @Singleton(name="MySingletonBean")
 */
class MySingletonBean extends \Stackable
{
    protected $counter = 0;

    public function raiseMe()
    {
        return $this->counter++;
    }
}
```

Implementation inside a Servlet is pretty straight forward and works like a charm, but I can't find any documentation on getting access to this in a plain php file outside a Servlet.

I'd expect it so be rather simple like:

```
<?php

use MyVendor\MyApp\MySingletonBean;

class IndexController extends App
{
    /**
     * maybe some funky annotations...
     *
     * @var \MyVendor\MyApp\MySingletonBean
     * @EnterpriseBean(name="MySingletonBean")
     */
    protected $mySingletonBean;

    public function index() {

        // and then servlet style...
        echo $this->mySingletonBean->raiseMe();

        // ... or like this?
        echo MySingletonBean::getInstance()->raiseMe();
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me into the right direction?

Thank you,

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SessionBeans exists as real PHP objects inside the container it is not possible to access them from e. g. a PHP-FPM application. To do so, we've implemented a client, that returns a proxy to the session bean and allows you to execute it's methods. Additional it is necessary to configure the persistence container itself, because by default, we've deactivated remote connections for security reasons.

So, the first thing you should do, is to install the `appserver-io/rmi` package as Composer requirement in your project, e. g.

```
$ composer install appserver-io/rmi
```

after that, you've to configure a server, that allows remote access to the persistence container, e. g. you can add the following XML snippet to the `<container name="combined-appserver">` in `etc/appserver/appserver.xml` file

```
<server
    name="persistence-container"
    type="\AppserverIo\Server\Servers\MultiThreadedServer"
    worker="\AppserverIo\Server\Workers\ThreadWorker"
    socket="\AppserverIo\Server\Sockets\StreamSocket"
    requestContext="\AppserverIo\Server\Contexts\RequestContext"
    serverContext="\AppserverIo\Appserver\Server\Contexts\StandardServerContext"
    streamContext="\AppserverIo\Server\Contexts\StreamContext"
    loggerName="System">

<params>
    <param name="admin" type="string">info@appserver.io</param>
    <param name="transport" type="string">tcp</param>
    <param name="address" type="string">127.0.0.1</param>
    <param name="port" type="integer">8585</param>
    <param name="workerNumber" type="integer">4</param>
    <param name="workerAcceptMin" type="integer">3</param>
    <param name="workerAcceptMax" type="integer">8</param>
    <param name="documentRoot" type="string">webapps</param>
    <param name="directoryIndex" type="string">index.pc</param>
    <param name="keepAliveMax" type="integer">64</param>
    <param name="keepAliveTimeout" type="integer">5</param>
    <param name="errorsPageTemplatePath" type="string">resources/templates/www/error.phtml</param>
</params>

<environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable condition="" definition="LOGGER_ACCESS=Access" />
</environmentVariables>

<connectionHandlers>
    <connectionHandler type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\ConnectionHandlers\HttpConnectionHandler" />
    <!-- connectionHandler type="\AppserverIo\Appserver\MessageQueue\ConnectionHandlers\AmqpConnectionHandler" / -->
</connectionHandlers>

<accesses>
    <!-- per default allow everything -->
    <access type="allow">
        <params>
            <param name="X_REQUEST_URI" type="string">.*</param>
        </params>
    </access>
</accesses>

<modules>
    <!-- REQUEST_POST hook -->
    <module type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\Modules\AuthenticationModule"/>
    <module type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\Modules\VirtualHostModule"/>
    <module type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\Modules\EnvironmentVariableModule" />
    <module type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\Modules\RewriteModule"/>
    <module type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\Modules\DirectoryModule"/>
    <module type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\Modules\AccessModule"/>
    <module type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\Modules\CoreModule"/>
    <module type="\AppserverIo\Appserver\PersistenceContainer\PersistenceContainerModule" />
    <!-- RESPONSE_PRE hook -->
    <module type="\AppserverIo\WebServer\Modules\DeflateModule"/>
    <!-- RESPONSE_POST hook -->
    <!-- module type="\AppserverIo\Appserver\Core\Modules\ProfileModule"/ -->
</modules>

<fileHandlers>
    <fileHandler name="persistence-container" extension=".pc" />
</fileHandlers>

</server>
```

below the `message-queue` server configuration.

Finally you can connect to the persistence container and call the `raiseCounter()` method of the `ASingletonProcessor` SessionBean of our example application with

```
<?php

use AppserverIo\RemoteMethodInvocation\RemoteConnectionFactory;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$connection = RemoteConnectionFactory::createContextConnection();
$connection->injectPort(8585);
$connection->injectAddress('127.0.0.1');
$connection->injectTransport('http');
$connection->injectAppName('example');

$session = $connection->createContextSession();
$session->setSessionId(md5('test'));
$proxy = $session->createInitialContext()->lookup('ASingletonProcessor');

echo $proxy->raiseCounter() . PHP_EOL;
```

The example uses a dummy Session-ID generated with `md5('test)` which is for testing purposes only. In a real life application you will use the default PHP Session-ID for example.

Hope that give's you an good impression how things could go :)